# jqgrid rowobject value is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid

I use the following code for bind the values in jqgrid.

And i create one link button for access the Particular Action Method.

I need to pass the firstcolumn value to the action method.

But ,If i use this Following **href='@Url.Action("ViewApplicants", "HR")?JobsID="+rowObject[0]+" '**.It show the undefined Value .How to solve this?

```
 <div>
        <table id="Jobtable"></table>
        <div id="jQGridPager"></div>
        <div id="dialog" title="View Job Detail"></div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#Jobtable").jqGrid({
                    url: '/HR/PassJsonJob/',
                    datatype: "json",
                    mtype: 'GET',
                    colNames: ['Job ID', 'Job Title', 'Job Experience', 'Job Location', 'ViewApplicants'],
                    colModel: [
                                { name: 'JobsID', index: 'JobsID', width: 150, align: 'left', editable: true },
                                { name: 'JobTitle', index: 'JobTitle', width: 150, align: 'left', editable: true },
                                { name: 'JobExperience', index: 'JobExperience', width: 150, align: 'left', editable: true },
                                { name: 'JobLocation', index: 'JobLocation', width: 150, align: 'left', editable: true },
                                {
                                    name: 'ViewApplicants', index: 'ViewApplicants', width: 150, sortable: false,
                                    formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
                                        alert(rowObject)
                                        return "<a href='@Url.Action("ViewApplicants", "HR")?JobsID="+rowObject[0]+"'>View Applicants</a>";
                                     }
                                }
                    ],
                    rowNum: 10,
                    rowList: [10, 20, 30],
                    viewrecords: true,
                    loadonce: true,
                    gridview: true,
                    pager: "#jQGridPager",
                    cellEdit: false,
                    rowNumbers: true,
                    width: 1000,
                    caption: 'Applied Jobs',
                    viewrecords: true
                })
                $('#Jobtable').jqGrid('navGrid', '#jQGridPager',
                {
                    edit: true,
                    add: false,
                    del: false,
                    view: false,
                    search: false
                });
            });


        </script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's important to know the format of the server response from the URL `/HR/PassJsonJob/`. The format of `rowObject` corresponds to the format of items from the server response. So it could be that `rowObject.JobsID` instead of `rowObject[0]` would correct way to access `JobsID` property. Because you use `loadonce: true` the format of `rowObject` could be `rowObject[0]` **at the first load**. Later, for example, at local paging or sorting of data, the format of `rowObject` will be object with `JobsID` property, so `rowObject.JobsID` will be correct.

So the usage of `rowObject.JobsID` or `rowObject[0] || rowObject.JobsID` could fix your problem.

One more option could be to use the property `key: true` in the definition of `JobsID` column in `colModel`. One can use the property only if `JobsID` contains **unique** values in every row. In the case jqGrid will use the value from `JobsID` column as rowid: the value of `id` attribute assigned to the rows (`<tr>` elements) of the grid. In the case one could use `options.rowId` to access the  `JobsID` value.

**UPDATED:** One more option exists in [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) fork, which I develop since the end of 2014. The 2-d parameter (`options`) of the custom formatter has the property `rowData`, which contains the same information like `rowObject`, but it has always object format. Thus it's safe to use `options.rowData.JobsID` instead of `rowObject[0] || rowObject.JobsID`. One don't need to use the 3-d parameter of the the custom formatter at all. Free jqGrid didn't changed the format of the 3-d parameter to have the best upwards compatibility to the previous versions of jqGrid.

Comment: Very helpful info about `loadonce: true` and grabbing the `rowObject` data - thank you Oleg!

Comment: @FastTrack: You are welcome! Additionally there are one more way which I implemented in [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) and which can be used in custom formatters. I can't modify the format of `rowObject` because of compatibility reason, but I extended `options` object with additional property `rowData` property which contains **always** the data in parsed named format. So one can use `options.rowObject.JobsID` instead of `rowObject[0] || rowObject.JobsID`. Even in case of reading from XML source the value from `options.rowObject.JobsID` will work.

Comment: Wow, great! Is there anything I should know if I want to start using `free jqGrid`? I'm currently using `jQGrid version 4.4.1`

Comment: @FastTrack: I tried to hold maximum compatibility to the old versions, but it could be still some problems mostly, where I fixed some old bugs, but old program used the bugs indirectly. I would recommend you just try jqGrid by changing URLs to URLs from CDN. See [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs). Free jqGrid contains many new features which are described in readme of every version and in many wiki articles. So I would recommend you to look through the wiki articles after the first test.

Comment: @FastTrack: If you would have some problems with free jqGrid then you can ask new question on stackoverflow or to write new issue on GitHub (see [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/issues)). You can see already more as 100 closed issues.